# How can I extract an X509 certificate from a smart card using Java?

Tags: java, smartcard

I use the [OmniKey 3121 reader](http://www.hidglobal.com/sites/hidglobal.com/files/resource_files/ok-3121-usb-ds-en_0.pdf) and can use the `javax.smartcardio` API to send APDU commands to the card reader. I'm not sure if there is a standard way to access the certificate stored on the card. Pointers to example code to read the certificate data would greatly help.

Also, can the [SUN PKCS#11 library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html#Intro) help in extracting the certificate from the smart card? It seems that this library can help with parsing the certificate and extracting field values, but can it also extract/export the certificate itself from the smart card?

Comment: does this thing have an API? I did a quick search, but I don't seem to find anything.

Comment: [PKCS#10](http://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/standards-initiatives/pkcs10-certification-request-syntax-standard.htm) is a Certificate Signing *Request* protocol. It isn't relevant to your question.

Comment: Yes, I realise that PKCS#10 is not relevant to my question. I've edited my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could extract the certificate using the SUN PKCS#11 provider library. Details provided in the following article helped: http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/10936_3587361_8/Java-Applet-for-Signing-with-a-Smart-Card.htm

Answer (score 0):

[As far as I know] It highly depends on the applet implementation on the card and also the card implementation itself. I mean, the card-applet programmer specify the commands that you must send to work with his/her applet and the form of their response also. So without the documentation of the applet that generate/verify your X509 certificate, you can't write the client-side application.

Answer (score 0):

A X.509 certificate is just passive data for the card. It is never evaluated by the card, but just send outside upon request. So the method for accessing a certificate is determined by the outside world, most likely according to PKCS 15 or ISO 7816-15 respectively. As already pointed out, additional documentation is at least useful or even necessary (if  7816-15 does not help).